# Android Custom Map

Tags: android, dictionary, positioning, gis

I am developing an Indoor Positioning System for Android. I need to draw a custom floor plan of a building and overlay a pointer on it.

In this scenario, which software/API I should use to draw custom floor plan?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did a library floorplan thing as part of my master's thesis. I settled for a simple custom `Drawable` that just scaled a `Bitmap` (floorplan) to fit the screen and then draws some translucent rectangles (book shelves) on top of it. My layout has a generic `View` with `fill_parent` for  both directions and gets the custom `Drawable` via `setBackgroundDrawable()` in `Activity.onCreate()`.

If you have high-resolution maps (more than fits into app memory in one piece), want zooming or even rotation, it's going to be a lot of work. I tried to use the Google IO app code mentioned by Reno in his answer, custom Google Maps overlays (can't zoom in close enough), an offline `WebView` (for the "free" zooming functionality) and even pondered a custom tile-based rendering system -- in the end using a simple `Bitmap` was the least hassle and worked surprisingly well for my use case.

I'd be very much interested in a solution that does zoomable, rotating, tiled-based rendering, though :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's helpful.  Which tool you use to draw Bitmap(floor plan)?

Comment: This was a prototype for a single library floor, so I just snapped a picture of a fire evacuation plan with my phone and cleaned it up in graphics program (Gimp); for the actual finished app, I'll probably trace the picture into vector graphics (using Inkscape) and then export to PNG (less trouble than SVG support on Android)

Comment: `I'd be very much interested in a solution that does zoomable, rotating, tiled-based rendering, though :) ` - have you seen https://github.com/moagrius/TileView? I never tried it, but I might have to and I'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

Google [did this for their Google I/O event](http://www.google.com/codesearch#qVeKhv9ZTQE/map/map.js&package%3ahttp://iosched%5C.googlecode%5C.com). Too bad they used javascript :( I'm no good at it.

They loaded the map.js in a `MapFragment`, which contains a `WebView`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Firstly, I need to find a way to draw a custom floor plan (map tile). I have been doing research on this in the past few days. I'm frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

The MapView component provides a very flexible method of adding custom elements of any kind to a map called MapOverlays. You can implement ItemizedOverlay and add items to it and define Drawables for Overlay Items on this overlay. After you've registered your Overlay at the MapView, the view takes care of when to draw your Items and where on the screen.

For more details and a tutorial, see http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html